# If $p~ \mid~ m^p + n^p$, prove $p~ \mid~ \frac{m^p + n^p}{m+n}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p \mid m^p + n^p$, and $p$ is a prime greater than $2$, prove $$p \mid \frac{m^p + n^p}{m+n}.$$

No clue how to start. Clearly $p \mid m + n$, but then what. I feel very less information is given. Yet primes are full of surprises.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not true for $m=n=1$ and $p=2$.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a very recent question, but I can't sem to find the duplicate...

Comment: @Goos Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Goos The "duplicate" mark is incorrect. This question implies the older question, but if $p^2\mid m+n$ then the original problem doesn't imply this one.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that's a good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : see $m \equiv -n$ $(\text {mod} p)$. Now factorise the part $\dfrac{m^p + n^p}{m + n}$ and then apply $m \equiv -n$ $(\text {mod} p)$.

Comment: This is a simpler answer than the other question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add arbitrary terms of the form $pm^an^b$ to the right side, and it will remain true. Then try using binomial theorem.